# How do I Handle Database changes and port my data?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, turbogears

Example, for web applications using Turbogears and SQLAlchemy.  Every time I update my data model, I need to delete my database and recreate it.

Is there an easy way to update the production database?

Do I have to write a custom script that transfers all the production data into a new database model?  Or is there an easier way to upgrade a production database?

Comment: Do you need to pull any of the existing data and import it into the recreated database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These database changes are called schema migrations. For SQLAlchemy, [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) is the defacto standard. Other ORMs/abstraction layers have similar solutions, e.g. [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for Django.

Answer (score 1):

You can [ALTER TABLE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php), i think that's the easiest way.